# UnsatisfiedLinkError while listening to kafka topic using spring-kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, snappy

I am getting below error while listening to a kafka topic through a Kafka-Consumer application that I wrote. Not sure if this is the problem with my system or with the project. I see that snappy is bundled as part of spring project itself so should not be issue with my system.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

- Spring Boot: 2.1.7
- Spring Kafka: 2.3.0
- JDK: 11.0.4
- Project Build System: OS X, Intellij Idea 2019.02

```
2019-12-07 21:01:12.740 Error while stopping the container: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/t9/mdy_gddj7yq4l13675rs22rx96jqs9/T/snappy-1.1.7-1ce9dfaf-b4ec-41ba-8a64-a52a9ed6e6c9-libsnappyjava.jnilib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/t9/mdy_gddj7yq4l13675rs22rx96jqs9/T/snappy-1.1.7-1ce9dfaf-b4ec-41ba-8a64-a52a9ed6e6c9-libsnappyjava.jnilib, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /private/var/folders/t9/mdy_gddj7yq4l13675rs22rx96jqs9/T/snappy-1.1.7-1ce9dfaf-b4ec-41ba-8a64-a52a9ed6e6c9-libsnappyjava.jnilib: code signature in (/private/var/folders/t9/mdy_gddj7yq4l13675rs22rx96jqs9/T/snappy-1.1.7-1ce9dfaf-b4ec-41ba-8a64-a52a9ed6e6c9-libsnappyjava.jnilib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2617)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:767)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1831)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:179)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:154)
    at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.hasNextChunk(SnappyInputStream.java:435)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyInputStream.read(SnappyInputStream.java:466)
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.ByteUtils.readVarint(ByteUtils.java:168)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecord.readFrom(DefaultRecord.java:293)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$1.readNext(DefaultRecordBatch.java:264)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:569)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.record.DefaultRecordBatch$RecordIterator.next(DefaultRecordBatch.java:538)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.nextFetchedRecord(Fetcher.java:1452)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1487)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1600(Fetcher.java:1332)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:645)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:606)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1294)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1225)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1201)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:993)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:949)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:901)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My project gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
    ***
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.7.RELEASE"
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'***

    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1212.jre7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.10.0'
    compile group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-registry-prometheus', version: '1.3.0'

    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.7.RELEASE"
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.kafka', name: 'spring-kafka-test', version: '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '1.4.200'
    testCompile group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: '4.0.1'
}
```

> UPDATE:
>
> I got a hint from [this](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1211) post and updated the Open-JDK to
> ***11.0.5*** from ***11.0.4***. Now I no longer see that issue.

Comment: The error `not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.` leads me to [this page](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-build/issues/1211), which indicates it's a bug in 11.0.4, and should be addressed by running 11.0.5?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even I got that info and trying to install 11.0.5. Will give update once I install that and try out

Comment: It turned out that the issue is with the JDK itself. Although while trying out many things I have downgraded the Spring Boot and Spring Kafka versions to 2.2.4, now I will try updating them to the latest and see if everything works fine.